# How to select all components on Top layer in Altium PCB?

Tags: pcb, components, altium, multi-layer

How can I select all components on Top layer of a multi-layer PCB in Altium without selecting the route traces?

And is there any way to select all components on both Top and Bottom layers together?

Answer (score 2):

Use "Find Similar Objects" and select the layer you want (or "Any").

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. I would suggest using the [PCB Filter](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-pnl-pcbfilterpcb-filter-ad) panel:

[image]